# Print the data and size from return call;

Tags: c, return

Here i need to print the data and the size of the data in this function call  **CDCDSerialDriver_Read()** which is returning the status of the operation.

```
static inline uint32_t CDCDSerialDriver_Read(void *data, uint32_t size, TransferCallback callback, void *argument)
{
    printf("CDCDSerialDriver_Read:\n\r");
    return CDCDSerial_Read(data, size, callback, argument);
}
```

Is there any way to print the data & size before the return call in this function. 
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: There is a lot of information missing: **What have you tried printing?**, does `CDCDSerial_Read` return a `uint32_t`, etc etc

Comment: How about saving the result, printing, and then return the result?

Comment: im trying to print the size and data. where i need to give print  statement. for printing the data?

Comment: רועי אבידן  is fine. How i need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in comments to question - the easiest way is to save result after function call and then return it after print.

```cpp
static inline uint32_t CDCDSerialDriver_Read(void *data, uint32_t size, TransferCallback callback, void *argument)
{
    printf("CDCDSerialDriver_Read:\n\r");
    uint32_t res = CDCDSerial_Read(data, size, callback, argument);
    // TODO: print everithing you want
    return res;
}
```

Comment: no problem. just saw you did not catch idea written by רועי אבידן

Comment: @crackhead.h If this answer solved your problem, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).